# having problems using Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::createRow()

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db

I have built a model that extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract and I can't figure  out why I can't use createRow(); here is my code:

```
class Model_User extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
   public function createUser()
   {
       $row = $this->createRow();
       $row->name = 'test';
       $row->save();
   }
}
```

and in a controller I use:

```
$userModel = new Model_User();
$userModel->createUser();
```

which when run displays an error

> An error occurred
>
> Application error

here is my setup in application.ini

```
resources.db.adapter = "pdo_mysql"
resources.db.params.host = "localhost"
resources.db.params.username = "root"
resources.db.params.password = "pass"
resources.db.params.dbname = "app_db"
resources.db.isDefaultTableAdapter = true
```

I am sure that my user/pass/dbname is correct.

I would appreciate it if you point me in the right direction.

Comment: Switch your application env to `development` and make sure you put `resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1` for development section in your application.ini. You'll get much more verbose exception info.

Comment: resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1 didn't produce any more information.

Answer (score 0):

Vika's hint is correct though you should add all the following to the development section of your app.ini file

```
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1
```

Then you (and we) will get much more information about what's wrong

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your `ErrorController` class has code to show you the errors. If you remove the code which displays the `Exception` then you'll never know what is wrong.